# Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Parameters' accepts this number of arguments

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I have upgraded a VB.net application from 2.0 to 4.6.

I am getting below error in the piece of code

> System.MissingMemberException: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Parameters' accepts this number of arguments.

What may be the issue?

```
Private Function MyFunction123(ByRef oXMLConfigData As XmlNodeList, ByRef oCmdCommandCol As ArrayList, ByVal iCmdCount As Integer, ByRef oReturnDataset As ReturnValues) As Boolean

    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim iRetVal As Integer
    Dim oCNode As XmlNode       
    Dim retVal As Boolean = False

    iRetVal = oCmdCommandCol(iCmdCount).Parameters(oCNode.ChildNodes(iCount).Attributes("SPParameter").Value).Value
    oCNode.ChildNodes(iCount).InnerText = iRetVal
    oReturnDataset.ReturnValues.AddReturnValuesRow(oCNode.Attributes("Name").Value, oCNode.ChildNodes(iCount).Attributes("Name").Value, oCNode.ChildNodes(iCount).InnerText)
    retVal = True
End Function
```

Function is called as

```
If Not MyFunction123(oXMLConfigSteps, oCmdCollection, iCountCmd, oReturnDataset) Then
    'Statements
End If
```

Comment: Your function name of "Function" is probably causing problems because the word "Function" is already used by VB,Net and is a reserved word that you can't use. Try changing the name to something more meaningful.

Comment: Sorry. I had modified actual functioname while posting

Comment: use that code directly without the function VS will tell you exactly which line is the issue

Comment: I have modified functionname in my question

Comment: You've got run-time error or a compile time error? Provide the function call.

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic It is a runtime error. function call is updated in question

Comment: An `ArrayList` is not recommended for new development. I wasn't aware that an `Object` had a `.Parameters ` collection. Can you possible change this to a `List(Of T)`? Why the `ByRef oCmdCommandCol`? It doesn't seem that oCmdCommandCol is being changed in this function.

Comment: `Exit` is not valid by itself. Exit what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

Arraylist "oCmdCommandCol" was filled with multiple SqlCommand objects hence and explicit type cast is required. I changed the code as below and it worked. Hope it will help someone in similar situation.

```
Private Function MyFunction123(ByRef oXMLConfigData As XmlNodeList, ByRef oCmdCommandCol As ArrayList, ByVal iCmdCount As Integer, ByRef oReturnDataset As ReturnValues) As Boolean

    Dim iCount As Integer
    Dim iRetVal As Integer
    Dim oCNode As XmlNode       
    Dim retVal As Boolean = False

'Changed code -Start-

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    cmd = New SqlCommand()
    cmd = CType(oCmdCommandCol(iCmdCount), SqlCommand)
    iRetVal =  cmd.Parameters(oCNode.ChildNodes(iCount).Attributes("SPParameter").Value).Value

'Changed code -End-

    oCNode.ChildNodes(iCount).InnerText = iRetVal
    oReturnDataset.ReturnValues.AddReturnValuesRow(oCNode.Attributes("Name").Value, 
    oCNode.ChildNodes(iCount).Attributes("Name").Value, oCNode.ChildNodes(iCount).InnerText)
    retVal = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the MyFunction123 method called, is it inside another function and outside the current class where it is declared, Since your function "MyFunction123" is Private, and if you are calling it outside the class you have to change access modifier or protected or public.
Also change EXIT to "Exit Function" if call is inside another function.

Comment: It is called from within the class from another private function. Please ignore Exit statement . Consider it as a placeholder.